# Nullable entity manager using JSF, Spring and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-entitymanager

I have a problem with the entity manager, it returns null. I have configured `persistence.xml` and `applicationContext.xml` and when I create a test class the Junit works and create the tables in the database.

But when I try do insert with jsf the entity manager returns always null.
It's a spring project with hibernate and jsf and this is the code source
of my class bean

```
package net.sid.eboutique.metier;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

import net.sid.eboutique.entities.Utilisateur;
import net.sid.eboutique.service.UserDao;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class UserBean {

private  UserDao managerDao;

    public Utilisateur user;

    public UserBean(){
        managerDao = new UserDao();
    }

    public void creerUser(){
        managerDao.creerUser(user);
    }

    public Utilisateur getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(Utilisateur user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

and this is my daoclass

```
package net.sid.eboutique.service;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;
import net.sid.eboutique.entities.Utilisateur;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

public class UserDao {

    private Utilisateur user;

    @PersistenceContext 
    public EntityManager em;

    public void creerUser(Utilisateur user) {
         em.persist(user);
    }

}
```

and this is the page xhtml

```
<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">

        <h:outputLabel value="Nom" for="name" />
        <h:inputText id="name" value="#{userBean.user.nom}" />
        <h:outputLabel value="Email" for="mail" />
        <h:inputText id="mail" value="#{userBean.user.email}" />
        <h:outputLabel value="Telephone" for="tel" />
        <h:inputText id="tel" value="#{userBean.user.tel}" />
        <h:outputLabel value="Adresse" for="adresse" />
        <h:inputText id="adresse" value="#{userBean.user.adresse}" />
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:form>
        <h:commandButton action="#{userBean.creerUser}" value="Save" />
    </h:form>
</h:form>
```

this is my applicationContext.xml :

```
<bean id="datasource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"></property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/eboutique"></property>
    <property name="username" value="root"></property>
    <property name="password" value="root"></property>
</bean>

<bean id="persistenceUnitManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
    <property name="defaultDataSource" ref="datasource"></property>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"></property>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="UN_EBOUTIQUE"></property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
```

Comment: Please, provide your spring application context configuration.

Comment: Looks OK. No error on startup?

Comment: Where did you inject the `EntityManager`, into a plain Java class? No designation like `@Service` or `@Repository` (from `org.springframework.stereotype`) is seen over the class `UserDao`. Do you use declarative Spring transactions? In that case, no annotation like `@Transactional` (from `org.springframework.transaction.annotation`) is seen. Besides, this is not related to JSF at all. You may want to remove the  whole JSF noise to list the question at another better place.